# How can I remove rows with N/A values after tabulating the database?

Tags: r, math, r-markdown, html-helper

This is the code itself. The issue arises when I tabulate the information; the table contains 'Na' values for species that are not found in the sample area. Therefore, I need to find a way to eliminate the rows that have at least one 'Na' value.

Librarys
library(knitr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tables)
library(xml2)
library(tinytex)
library(latexpdf)
library(tidyr)

```
DAPP0 <- tabular(("Tipo de Bosque" = DataP$Tipo_Bosque)*
                ("Especie" = Nombre_Cientifico) ~ 
                ("DAP" = DAP) *  
                ((Media = mean) + 
                    (DS = sd) +
                    (Varianza = var) +   
                    (Mínimo = min) + 
                    (Máximo = max) + 
                    (Mediana = median) ), 
                    data = DataP)

html.tabular( DAPPF0,
      options = htmloptions( HTMLcaption = "Tabla Dap por Especie",
                             justification = "c",
                             pad = TRUE ) )
```

[image]

Thanks for the help

i try using this

```
DAPPF0 <- DAPP0 %>%
  filter(!is.na(DS) & !is.na(Mediana))

DAPPF0 <- datos[complete.cases(datos), ]

DAPPF0 <- na.omit()
```

dput(DataP):
structure(list(Localidad = c("Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus",
"Mallin Quetrus", "Mallin Quetrus", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte",
"Valle Norte", "Valle Norte", "Valle Norte"), Tipo_Bosque = structure(c(3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Bosque puro", "Krummholz",
"Lenga Mixto"), class = "factor"), Parcela = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 3, 3), Altitud = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 940, 940, 940, 940,
940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940,
940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940,
940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940,
940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940, 940,
940, 940, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928,
928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928,
928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928,
928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 928, 896, 896, 896, 896,
896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896,
896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896,
896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896,
896, 896), Especie = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L,
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L,
5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L,
10L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("Chaura", "Chilco", "Coigue",
"Corcolen", "Lenga", "Luma", "Mañio de hojas punzantes", "Meli",
"Michay", "Sauco del diablo", "Zarzaparrilla"), class = "factor"),
Nombre_Cientifico = structure(c(7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 1L,
8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 8L,
5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), levels = c("Amomyrtus luma",
"Amomyrtus meli", "Azara lanceolata", "Berberis darwinii",
"Fucsia magallanica", "Gaultheria mucronata", "Nothofagus dombeyi",
"Nothofagus pumilio", "Podocarpus nubigenus", "Raukaua laetevirens",
"Ribes punctatum"), class = "factor"), DAP = c(16, 13, 5,
5, 8, 7.5, 8, 7, 17.5, 27, 35, 28, 31, 27, 20, 44, 52, 5,
43, 49, 10, 38, 7, 8, 5, 7, 18, 8, 7, 33, 34, 6.5, 5.5, 5,
10, 23, 23, 27, 32, 33, 25, 8, 30, 14.5, 20, 8, 22, 21, 33,
23, 13, 11, 30, 13, 9, 10, 12, 13, 28, 48, 10, 14, 7, 8,
11, 35, 40, 17, 13, 20, 8, 6, 40, 28, 17, 26, 18, 17, 12,
14, 18, 15, 9, 8, 8, 6, 18, 60, 40, 30, 21, 38, 14, 48, 18,
24, 8, 22, 18, 25, 18, 20, 69, 19, 20, 23, 18, 20, 28, 120,
160, 74, 152, 54, 20, 22, 16, 32, 11, 21, 19, 32, 104, 42,
32, 52, 70, 20, 123, 140, 12, 19, 16, 26, 42, 152, 30, 135,
29, 29, 32, 40, 35, 57, 60, 150, 20, 85, 118, 18, 30, 21,
26, 22, 14, 113, 120, 90, 75, 162, 102, 70, 64, 48, 50, 40,
54, 78, 52, 80, 32, 40, 28, 98, 32, 43, 46, 52, 78, 39, 172,
32, 15, 60, 58, 15, 20, 25, 65, 40, 52, 51, 42, 62, 54, 200,
11, 9, 20, 17, 7, 11, 9, 17, 9, 11, 11, 7, 17, 23, 41, 34,
11, 40, 24, 24, 6, 7, 14, 7, 57, 47, 22, 14, 10, 7, 17, 24,
32, 46, 15, 16, 16, 17, 30, 16, 12, 14, 29, 14, 28, 16, 21,
20, 17, 16, 4, 15, 8, 9, 20, 12, 11, 6, 37, 9, 5, 5, 41,
4, 5, 17, 27, 20, 11, 6, 21, 6, 5, 24, 15, 6, 14, 22, 6,
15, 24, 10, 23, 12, 13, 50, 25, 18, 18, 6, 15, 10, 13, 11,
30, 25, 13, 8, 15, 22, 17, 17, 14, 10, 20, 18, 16, 14, 9,
5, 17, 8, 12, 13, 6, 12, 14, 22, 10, 15, 11, 7, 18, 40, 28,
20, 35, 11, 7, 25, 10, 13, 22, 9, 12, 16, 25, 25, 12, 16,
24, 20, 21, 16, 13, 28, 27, 9, 6), Estado_Sociologico = structure(c(2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L,
3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L,
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L,
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L,
5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L,
3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L,
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,
3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L,
3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L,
3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L,
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("Codominante",
"Dominante", "Intermedio", "Muerto", "Suprimido"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,
-345L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: `tidyr::drop_na(DataP)` and then use the `tabular()` code as you have at the early part of your question.

Comment: thanks but i tried and the code dosent correct the N/A problem, do you have any other method ?? thanks !!!! im in great pain

Comment: You'll need to provide the output of `dput(DataP)`, along with an indication of the packages you are using, as part of your question in order to make the problem reproducible.